# Detect app opening using a background service

Tags: android

I'm having trouble detecting when another apps are opened using a background service or listener. As soon as I start my application I launch the background service and what I'd like to do is make it detect when OTHER applications are launched (or resumed). How can I achieve this? I'm up to anything, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

you may want to look at [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html). The getRunningAppProcesses method or getRunningTasks method can give you access to currently running tasks or app processes. You can use this list to track running or recent app(s).

Comment: but is it possible to do this as soon as the app is opened?

Comment: you will need to do the book keeping, [please see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061179/broadcast-receiver-to-detect-application-start). For app restarts, you can create a broadcast [receiver for intent android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_RESTARTED)