# Android/Java: Notify upon app run

Tags: java, android

I have an Android service running in the background. Is it possible to be notified when a new app is being started and get the package name?

I could loop through the list of running apps every 10 seconds, but maybe there's a better way?

Comment: [STICKY Service that tracks all of the running application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061179/broadcast-receiver-to-detect-application-start) - be warned some parts of this are deprecated. You might want to do something on [these](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/package-summary.html) lines instead.

Comment: Thanks, however this is the same as I already have (checking every 10 seconds). I am looking for way to get an alert when someone starts an app.

Comment: Android.app.usage won't work below lollipop.

Comment: ^Yes that is true :)