# Nativescript detect other Apps

Tags: nativescript

Is there a way in Nativescript to detect when another App opens and if so then close it based on a setting flag?

I found a plugin http://plugins.nativescript.org/plugin/nativescript-applist that will list all apps on the phone

Answer (score 0):

NativeScript does not provide such a logic, neither internally nor as a plugin, afaik.

For the Android side you could realize this behavior by writing a background Service which is started at system boot time and periodically checks if apps have been started. Here is an [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061179/broadcast-receiver-to-detect-application-start) to an example on SO.

For the iOS side I think this is not possible, imho (correct me if am wrong).